# In CTsliding Up panel bottomController showing nil

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode10

I have issue in CTSlidingup panel its have problem.

its showing error

bottomController    CTSlidingUpPanel.CTBottomSlideController?   nil none .
its show above error how can i solve this ?
CTsliding Up panel bottomController showing nil

```
import UIKit
import CTSlidingUpPanel

class ViewController: UIViewController, CTBottomSlideDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
    var bottomController:CTBottomSlideController?;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bottomController = CTBottomSlideController(parent: view, bottomView: bottomView, tabController: self.tabBarController!, navController: self.navigationController, visibleHeight: 64)


        bottomController?.setAnchorPoint(anchor: 0.7)
        bottomController?.delegate = self;

        bottomController?.onPanelExpanded = {
            print("Panel Expanded in closure")
        }

        bottomController?.onPanelCollapsed = {
            print("Panel Collapsed in closure")
        }

        bottomController?.onPanelMoved = { offset in
            print("Panel moved in closure " + offset.description)
        }

        //Uncomment to specify top margin on expanded panel
        //bottomController?.setExpandedTopMargin(pixels: 100)

        if bottomController?.currentState == .collapsed
        {
            //do anything, i don't care
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        bottomController?.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func didPanelCollapse()
    {
        print("Collapsed");
    }
    func didPanelExpand(){
        print("Expanded")
    }
    func didPanelAnchor(){
        print("Anchored")
    }

    func didPanelMove(panelOffset: CGFloat)
    {
        print(panelOffset);
    }


}
```

or kindly suggest slideup panel lib. or give some examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't set your bottonView Referencing Outlets
[image]

if you don't set then set this

Answer (score 0):

Look, judging by your screenshot you don't have a **tabBarController**.

```
bottomController = CTBottomSlideController(parent: view, bottomView: bottomView, tabController: self.tabBarController!, navController: self.navigationController, visibleHeight: 64)
```

In your initializer if you use **self.tabBarController!**(Please notice the exclamation mark) and there's no **tabBarController** this line will throw an error

What you can do, as described in **README**, is provide **nil** to that parameter.